# Print IAM group policy JSON document using Python / Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

**Objective:**

Hi, I'm a newbie trying to write code to pull the inline policy document from an IAM Group and then print the JSON document.

---

I've found some similar posts but haven't found success referencing them:

- [List of all roles with attached policies with Boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66127551/list-of-all-roles-with-attached-policies-with-boto3)
- [How to get IAM Policy Document via boto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689157/how-to-get-iam-policy-document-via-boto)

---

**Boto3 Documentation:**

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_group_policy

---

I'm receiving the following **error:  TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable**

---

```
import boto3
import json

iam = boto3.client('iam')

def get_group_policy(group_name, policy_name):

# Define variable:
group_name = 'aws_iam_group_name'
policy_name = 'aws_policy_arn'

# Retrieves inline policy document embedded in IMA group.
# Returns: GroupName, PolicyName, and PolicyDocument
response = iam.get_group_policy(
    GroupName = group_name,
    PolicyName = policy_name
)

return (json.dumps(group_name, policy_name))

# Calls and prints function
var1 = get_group_policy
print(json.dumps(var1))
```

---

**I made some updates to the code based on what you said. Here are the changes:**

```
import boto3
import json

iam = boto3.client('iam')

# Define variable:
group_name = 'aws_iam_group_name'
policy_name = 'aws_policy_arn'

def get_group_policy(group_name, policy_name):

# Retrieves inline policy document embedded in IMA group.
# Returns: GroupName, PolicyName, and PolicyDocument
response = iam.get_group_policy(
    GroupName = group_name,
    PolicyName = policy_name
)

return (json.dumps(response))

# Calls and prints function
var1 = get_group_policy(group_name, policy_name)
#print(json.dumps(var1))
print(var1)
```

I receive the following error:

```
    WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 21.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sso-iam/sso-iam/create-permission-set.py", line 32, in <module>
    var1 = get_group_policy(group_name, policy_name)
  File "/sso-iam/sso-iam/create-permission-set.py", line 24, in get_group_policy
    response = iam.get_group_policy(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 388, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 708, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the GetGroupPolicy operation: The specified value for policyName is invalid. It must contain only alphanumeric characters and/or the following: +=,.@_-
```

I don't understand why it thinks the PolicyName is incorrect. I've tried copying the ARN directly from AWS and also using just the part after arn:aws:iam::#####:policy/itriedusingthispieceasPolicyName

Comment: Are you supplying the policy name (as opposed to the ARN)? Also, please fix your posted code's indentation. And, generally speaking, don't run scripts as root unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: I am supplying the policy name because if I supply the ARN it gives me an error indicating certain characters are not allowed which are part of the ARN. In other examples I've seen the policy name has also been supplied.

Comment: It's difficult to help here because the current state of your code and the associated symptoms seem to not reflect the current reality. For example your code indentation is wrong and you've suggested that you're supplying a policy name but your code has `policy_name = 'aws_policy_arn'` (i.e. suggests an ARN rather than name).

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your function. Your var1 is literally function object, not the result of it.

It should be

```
group_name = 'aws_iam_group_name'
policy_name = 'aws_policy_arn' 
var1 = get_group_policy(group_name, policy_name)
```

Also you don't need the names in your function, as they are arguments of it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I made changes to the code as recommended but also the print I changed to print(var1) because I didn't think I should have to use the json.dumps again since it was used at the return. I'm still receiving an error. I've edited/updated the original post.

Comment: @CalebNelsen I would suggest making new question with the new errors.